# on-screen keyboard and auto-rotation does not work on Lenovo YOGA 510-14ISK in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: lenovo, 22.04, onscreen-keyboard

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 the on-screen keyboard on Lenovo YOGA 510-14ISK (which is a convertible) does not open automatically nor when accessed via settings/accessibility.

(in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it worked fine on this machine)

I don't know if the second error is related to this: auto-rotation on Lenovo YOGA 510-14ISK doesn't work either after upgrading to 22.04 and the "rotation"-icon is not displayed in the top right menu either.

Do you think, this is a kernel problem? What I mean is: should I upgrade kernel 5.15 to 5.17?

Comment: From the answer to this question it seems that it may be related with Wayland:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414229/ubuntu-22-04-installed-and-i-dont-have-tablet-mode

Answer (score 2):

(copying my anwser from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414229/ubuntu-22-04-installed-and-i-dont-have-tablet-mode/1440948#1440948) so i can help you too)

hey so i had a similar problem, one solution was to use xorg instead of wayland (and that works but that's annoying) another solution that is kind of a workaround is to install the following gnome extensions

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5389/screen-rotate/
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4316/force-show-osk/

basically all functionality is restored (screen auto-rotation + on screen keyboard) without having to use xorg