# Ubuntu 22.04 installed And I don't have Tablet mode! :(

Tags: lenovo

When I use the LiveUSB, I have this functionality enabled and fully functional.

But once I have installed it on the computer, a LENOVO YOGA 530, the "tablet mode" stops working. :(

With this command:

```
udevadm info --export-db | grep -I iio
```

I have this output:

```
P: /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ITE8396:00/0018:048D:8396.0001/HID-SENSOR-200073.3.auto/iio:device0
N: iio:device0 E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ITE8396:00/0018:048D:8396.0001/HID-SENSOR-200073.3.auto/iio:device0
E: SUBSYSTEM=iio
E: DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device0
E: DEVTYPE=iio_device
E: IIO_SENSOR_PROXY_TYPE=iio-poll-accel iio-buffer-accel
E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=iio-sensor-proxy.service
E: SUBSYSTEM=iio
```

Executing the command:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/iio-sensor-proxy -v -r
```

And, after that, I turning screen more then 180°, and receive this kind of message:

```
** (iio-sensor-proxy:11912): DEBUG: 18:22:47.147: Emitted orientation changed: from undefined to normal
** (iio-sensor-proxy:11912): DEBUG: 18:22:56.260: Emitted orientation changed: from normal to right-up
** (iio-sensor-proxy:11912): DEBUG: 18:22:59.766: Emitted orientation changed: from right-up to bottom-up
** (iio-sensor-proxy:11912): DEBUG: 18:23:01.870: Emitted orientation changed: from bottom-up to right-up
** (iio-sensor-proxy:11912): DEBUG: 18:23:02.572: Emitted orientation changed: from right-up to normal
```

BUT the screen does nothing, it does not rotate.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. :(

Comment: I download te ISO: ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64 in the official ubuntu web... I don't install in my main system _betas, unofficial, nightly, etc_ for this I use a liveUSB, or similar...

Comment: What I did was:
Go to the website ubuntu.com
then to downloads
and from there I did the download.
The link is this:
https://ubuntu.com/#download-content

and from there I downloaded it from this link:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.04&architecture=amd64

The link of the button says:
22.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps - I had trouble with tablet mode detection, rotation and on-screen keyboard when running the wayland session, changing to the X session resolved these issues for me on 22.04.  I'm suspecting the live USB might use X, the default once installed is wayland (at least for Intel and AMD drivers)

Comment: Worked on a Lenovo Yoga L390. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hey so i had a similar problem, one solution was to use xorg instead of wayland (and that works but that's annoying) another solution that is kind of a workaround is to install the following gnome extensions

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5389/screen-rotate/
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4316/force-show-osk/

basically all functionality is restored (screen auto-rotation + on screen keyboard) without having to use xorg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).